# Is it possible to use where statements like I am trying to right now?

Tags: sql, triggers, sybase

I have 4 tables a "IN SHOP" table which has a variable "How many games in shop", no primary keys and 2 foreign keys of "Shop" where the primary key is ID and "Game" where the primary key is also ID.

Now I have a table "Purchase" which has a primary key of ID and foreign keys of "Shop ID" and "Game ID". Now I made a trigger that once a new PURCHASe has been added to the "PURCHASE table then every game number drops however I would like it to drop for one specific game in one specific shop.

Right now I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete 
AFTER INSERT ON purchase
BEGIN
    UPDATE In_SHOP
    SET HMGIS = HMGIS - 1
    WHERE IN_SHOP.SHOP_ID = PURCHASE.SHOP_ID
      AND IN_SHOP.GAME_ID = PURCHASE.ID_GAME
END
```

Comment: which database you are using ??

Comment: we are using SQL central but the data  is self made

Comment: Does that mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: Aaaah my bad, I forgot the name isn't the same. I believe I am using SYBASE

Comment: An after *INSERT* trigger named *DELETE* that does an *UPDATE* is rather comprehensive in its use of terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `inserted` view:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete AFTER INSERT ON purchase
BEGIN
    UPDATE In_SHOP
        SET HMGIS= HMGIS-1
        FROM inserted i
    WHERE IN_SHOP.SHOP_ID = i.SHOP_ID AND IN_SHOP.GAME_ID = i.ID_GAME;
END;
```

You specifically asked about a `WHERE` clause.  This would often be written using `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete AFTER INSERT ON purchase
BEGIN
    UPDATE s
        SET HMGIS = HMGIS - 1
        FROM IN_SHOP s JOIN
             inserted i
             ON s.SHOP_ID = i.SHOP_ID AND s.GAME_ID = i.ID_GAME;
END;
```